# Project and Item Templates for team

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Is there anyway of hosting Project and Item Templates in VS Team Services and hooking Visual Studio 2015 to include them and offering them as options to our internal developers for Project Templates for us to use instead of the standard out-of-the-box ones.

**Edit**

Item Templates are for the templates you see when you press **New Item** in VS (example when you add a new class or interface).

Project Templates are what you see when you press **New Project** in VS.

[MSDN explaining VS templates.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Quick video showing Item Templates.](https://youtu.be/mIBcU4srCK0)

Comment: What's a "project template"? What's an "item template"?

Comment: @daniel Mann edited the post with more info. Does this help?

Comment: @DanielMann did that help (edited post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload your project/item templates into VSTS Source Control but there isn't any way to hook VS to use them.

The alternative way for your scenario would be [Creating Private Gallery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx) or [Configure a SharePoint Site as a Private Gallery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266718.aspx) which can be integrated with VS.